# Spring @RequestParam doesn't handle multiple variables correctly - example test case

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The test case given below shows a simple case where I have 2 parameters `paramA` and `paramB`.

- If I call the `/paramtest` url the `paramtest()` method is called.
- If I enter `true` for `paramA`, method `aTrue()` is called.
- However, when I enter `true` for both `paramA` and `paramB` the method `bTrueNotA()` is called.

But the 3rd `@RequestMapping` calls for `A=True` and `B!=true`. By my reconing when both parameters are true, `aTrue()` should be called.

```
@RequestMapping("paramtest")
@ResponseBody
public String paramtest(){
    return  "<html><head></head><body>" +
                "<form action=paramtest method=post>" +
                    "paramA: <input type=text name=paramA /><br>" +
                    "paramB: <input type=text name=paramB /><br>" +
                    "<input type=submit>" + 
                "</form>" +
            "</body></html>";       
}

@RequestMapping(value="paramtest", params="paramA=true")
@ResponseBody
public String aTrue(){
    return "A=true";
}

@RequestMapping(value="paramtest", params={"paramB=true", "paramA!=true"})
@ResponseBody
public String bTrueNotA(){
    return "B=True; A!=true";
}
```

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: What happens if you change "paramA!=true" to "!paramA=true"?

Comment: Good idea. Tried that, but doesn't solve it: When b=true and a=false (or a is nothing, null) paramtest() is called. When I use paramA!=true it calls that method only depending on paramB, but when I do !paramA=true it never calls bTrueNotA().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a bug in Spring. I tried with the following mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/paramtest", params={"paramA=true"})
@ResponseBody
public String function A() { return "A"; }

@RequestMapping(value="/paramtest", params={"paramA=true", "paramB=foobar"})
@ResponseBody
public String function B() { return "B"; }

@RequestMapping(value="/paramtest", params={"paramA=!true", "paramB=foo"})
@ResponseBody
public String function C() { return "C"; }
```

and using your existing form with the following parameters, these were the results I got:

`paramA=true` A() called as expected

`paramA=true, paramB=foobar` B() called as expected

`paramA=not_true, paramB=foo` 404 page, and not C() as expected.

I got this error on the Tomcat console:

```
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver 142 - No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/paramtest', method 'POST', parameters map['paramB' -> array<String>['foo'], 'paramA' -> array<String>['not_true']]
```

All of this with Spring 3.0.5. Note that the `myParam!=myValue` was only available from Spring 3.0.4 onwards (the [3.0.3 doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29) does not list that option). Also, I do not think that `!myParam=myValue` is valid, as this is not listed in the [current 3.0.5 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29).

Sorry this is not a solution to your problem but wanted to share my investigation :)

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I've also posted on their forum with no response. I'll post a JIRA about this. It's always good to know that others can re-produce the problem.

Comment: This was confirmed as a bug in the JIRA: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8059?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs